# How to Upload images to Php server and store in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am basically tring to upload image from android and upload it to php server but here i'm not getting any connection with this code or image upload 
.
I'm getting this error .

```
Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: host name
```

but as per my knowledge i given correct connection and php file also in correct domain. 
Look at my code :
UploadImage.java

```
public class UploadImage extends Activity {
InputStream inputStream;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);   
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server.com/uploadimage/uploadimage.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
            Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

         String res = "";
         StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
         inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
         int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
         Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         if (contentLength < 0){
         }
         else{
                byte[] data = new byte[512];
                int len = 0;
                try
                {
                    while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                    {
                        buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try
                {
                    inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..

                Toast.makeText(UploadImage.this, "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
         }
         return res;
    }
```

}

**Php Code :**

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
 $binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';?>
```

Any one known this issue ? if any one know how to store in mysql database from php file and fetch viceversa please suggest me here...

Comment: If you are testing on emulator, Once restart your emulator sometimes it is giving this exception but after restart it will work well. You can also check the internet connection by opening inbuilt browser of the emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is very clear ...

```
Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: host name
```

means that the `HttpPost` cannot make a connection using the hostname you supplied - because the hostname you supplied isn't known.

If you take the hostname from this line :

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server.com/uploadimage/uploadimage.php");
```

and put it in a browser on the same device what happens ... i suggest you will get an error saying unable to connect to host. If this works then i suggest you check the following line is in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also ensure that the PHP file contains the following header if your using a `JPEG`:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
```

Comment: i'm getting correct echo when i use this line in browser and now at present getting content length = -1 .. can u see y n wat to do next ..

Answer (score 4):

```
1. Need to add Internet permission in android manifest file .
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

2. Every Time i used to see image using url but unable to see because i didnt added 
      echo "<img src=test.jpg>";
3.$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');

4. final thing is i have to change header file as :

header('Content-Type: image/jpg; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Host configuration and choose right header for file upload. In your php code you have given wrong header type.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you as ManseUK said to add the permission in your Manifest.
This error is quite unclear but is often resolved by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

// change the bitmap compress format to jpeg
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

// then uploadimage.php

// note the imagecreatefromstring() function

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // in case its turned off and your not seeing errors  

ini_set('display_errors','1'); // confirm and browse to page  

if($base) {  
    $ttime = intval(time());  
    $quality = '100';  
    $save_to = 'images/img-' . $ttime . '.jpeg';  
    $binary=base64_decode($base);  
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($binary);  
    if ($im !== false) {  
        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');  
        $idno = ImageJPEG($im, $save_to, $quality);  
        imagedestroy($im);  
        echo "iid:" . $ttime;  
    } else {  
        echo "Error:" . $ttime;  
    }  
}
```