# how to get the file path and name in android?

Tags: android, android-image, android-file

I crated one image store in sd card to save that image and then i need that image path and name of the image pls tell  how to get the name and path of the image

```
      public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
 {
     String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                                 "/NewFolder";
         File dir = new File(file_path);
         if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
         File file = new File(dir, "myImage.png");




         FileOutputStream fOut;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);


             bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
             fOut.flush();
             fOut.close();

         String name =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
             "/NewFolder";
         storedimagepath=name.toString();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-path-of-image-on-android

Comment: thanks working..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got this

```
 void getImageCAMERandGALLERY()
    {

        final String [] items = new String[] { "Take from Camera" , "Select from Gallery" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , android.R.layout.select_dialog_item , items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog , int item)
                {

                    if (item == 0)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "tmp_avatar_"
                                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT , mImageCaptureUri);

                            try
                                {
                                    intent.putExtra("return-data" , true);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent , PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        } else
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Complete action using") , PICK_FROM_FILE);
                        }
                }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.show();

    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:


                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE:
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();



                break;

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null)
                    {
                        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                        UserImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
                        try
                            {

                                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext() , photo);
                                storeUriInFile(tempUri);
                            } catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }

        }

    }

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext , Bitmap inImage)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver() , inImage , "Title" , null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }


void storeUriInFile(Uri uri)
    {
        try
            {
                Bitmap my_btmp = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver() , uri); // BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BufferedInputStream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                my_btmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG , 0 , bos);
                byte [] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                long timeinmilliseconds = new Date().getTime();
                // store byte array in a image file
                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                File file = new File(filepath , SpeakerBox_FOLDER);
                if (!file.exists())
                    file.mkdirs();

                String mFileName = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mFileName);
                out.write(bitmapdata);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                String filename = mFileName;
                storedimagepath = filename;


            } catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like that

```
String name =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/NewFolder";
         storedimagepath=name.toString();

File f = new File(storedimagepath+"/photo.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```