# android camera : Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity

Tags: java, android, uri, android-camera-intent

i've really frustased to solve my problem, i have an application that using camera, when camera capture a photo, it will display on activity, when i'm not using `cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);` photo will display on activity, but the name and path file is not like what i wanted. i'm using galaxy tab for compiling it, i have follow tutorial to solve my problem from [here](http://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-path-of-image-on-android) and [here](https://github.com/deepwinter/AndroidCameraTester) but my application still force close and eror, this is my code :

```java
{
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File path = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/android/data/spaj_foto");
    path.mkdir();
    File file = new File (path,"spaj_foto.png");
    String filePath ="/android/data/spaj_foto/spaj_foto.png";

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {}       


    mPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, file.getPath());
    mPhotoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,TAKE_PHOTO_CODE );  

}
```

activityresult method :

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        image_spaj.setImageBitmap(photo);


        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
        File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

//              System.out.println(mImageCaptureUri);
    }  
}
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri mPhotoUri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mPhotoUri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

this is my logcat says:

```
    09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {org.example.touch/org.example.touch.FormSpaj}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3222)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at org.example.touch.FormSpaj.onActivityResult(FormSpaj.java:993)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
09-27 10:59:43.186: E/AndroidRuntime(31318):    ... 11 more
```

i really hope someone can help me to solve my problem, i already stack and can't thinking anyway again, please someone help me... thank you.

Comment: This is just a null pointer exception, what is the line FormSpaj.java:993?

Comment: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Comment: `getExtras()` can return null if there is no extras Bundle.  You should make sure the value returned from `getExtras()` isn't `null`.

Comment: my image is saved on my path that i wanted, i have no idea, why is this getting null

Comment: Also, you're setting the Extras with the "key" `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, but attempting to get the key `data` -- are you sure they are equal?  Edit:  They're not.  `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT == "output"`.

Comment: i think like that, is that false?

Comment: If you store the value with the "key" `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you'll of course want to fetch it using the same key, but definitely not "data".

Comment: @AoyamaNanami `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` add the configChanges for particular activity. Yesterday i had same problem. after add that configChanges its working fine. try it

Comment: android:configChanges is affected to camera result image ?  i did not understand, can yo please explain it ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you have both **Camera Permission** and **READ/WRITE External Storage** Permissions.

**Try this is working like charm with me**

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help... but i have one question, why when i capture another image, this is not rewrite the image that have created before?

Comment: because we generate unique uri in this method setImageUri() by appending current time milliseconds. If you want to overwrite the file give static hard coded file name in setImageUri() method.

Comment: i have made like this :  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/android/data/spaj_foto/spaj_foto.png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: This will not work like a charm for the Android version running above Android N,
only working for the Android Versions below N

Answer (score 7):

Try this, Yesterday i had same problem. using below code i rectify problem. just try on it.

Note : And also add `configChanges` for particular activity. while calling the camera intent activity will be refreshed. you need to avoid that. `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

```
btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            File file = new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    "test.jpg");

                            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            Log.d("TAG", "outputFileUri intent"
                                    + outputFileUri);
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                    outputFileUri);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("TAG", "outputFileUri RESULT_OK" + outputFileUri);
            if (outputFileUri != null) {

                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(outputFileUri,
                        image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

                if (bitmap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "the image data could not be decoded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Decoded Bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " x "
                                    + bitmap.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            Log.d("TAG", "datae" + targetUri);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(targetUri,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "the image data could not be decoded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Decoded Bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " x "
                                + bitmap.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Uri uri, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;

    try {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(uri), null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(uri), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return bm;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think following line causes the issue.

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

You pass the file uri already as following

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
```

When you pass EXTRA_OUTPUT with a URI, the intent you receive in onActivityResult() will be null. If you want to get image in this method, fetch image with the path you pass with EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Comment: This really works. I started facing crash issue on Android 7.0 and removing this line did the trick. Also removing this line didn't affect pre-nougat devices as well. Tested from Android 4.4 and above.

Comment: @Jose Jithin bro u r awesome