# Bitmap Factory Returning Null Bitmap Despite Size Restraints

Tags: android, bitmap

I am setting up an app to take photos, save their location, and show them in a gridview. I have one item that has a camera icon that when clicked will launch the camera app.

When I followed the example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), I was receiving an error about "failure to deliver result info". So I searched here and followed the accepted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042511/android-camera-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-0-resul) question. But, that accepted answer is constantly returning a null on the line here with decodeFile() on activity result:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
            Bitmap newImage = decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
            ImageItem takenPhoto = new ImageItem(newImage,"Photo Taken");
            gridAdapter.add(takenPhoto);

        }

    }
}


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

I know that the reason the bitmap is null is due to the size of the file, but I have minimized it as the answer said to.

Why is it still giving me a null response?

EDIT:

After some help from others, I figured it out. The Permissions were after the < application  > line in the manifest, and should have been before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it, but I suppose the error is due to the  `o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` is true till the end of the method. You should put it to false before create the bitmap.

Comment: I have put "o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;" before the return statement and then moved it to before the o2 bitmap factory creation statement. Both cases give me null image. I also tried changing o2.inJustDecodeBoundes to false before the return, also null image.

Comment: I have some time now. I'll test you code, just a sec.

Comment: I don't know what's your problem. I tested here and worked just fine. I could't test the "onActivityResult" part 'cause you have some undeclared variables there. So I'm thinking that your problem **could be on your string path**. Since I tested your code here and haven't any problems.

Comment: hm.  I'll keep looking, but no matter if I use this method, or the sample method on my galaxy, I get this response. Strange. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, since we opened a communication line here I'll give you another tip. You'll gonna need to with handle a lot of shit when dealing with bitmaps on Android. Concurrency for example, besides all the fuss concerning bitmap creation. I'll recommend some library like the Universal Loader:  https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
It can make your job a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah. I scrapped the whole activity and copy/pasted the accepted answer here to wipe the slate clean. At least now in the exception it tells me "file not found". Something is up there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83480/discussion-between-tin-megali-and-sparkysword).