# Display a fragment after taking a picture

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I work on a android application with a navigation bar on the left side. When I click on a button I can display my fragment, on another button I start the camera.

I want to take a picture and display it in my fragment but I have the following java runtime exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/photo.jpg }} to activity {com.example.fred.myApplication/com.example.fred.myApplication.MainActivity}:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

My code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FormFragment.OnFormFragmentInteractionListener {
private File mFichier;
private ImageView mImageView ;

// On déclare une constante dans la classe FirstClass
public final static int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1 ;
public final static String EXTRA_PICS_URI    = "com.example.fred.myapplication.PICS_URI";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("onActivityResult()", "start");
    Log.i("onActivityResult()", "requestCode : "+requestCode+" - Expected : " +REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Log.i("onActivityResult()", "resultCode : " + resultCode + " - Expected : " +RESULT_OK);

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(data != null){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Fragment fragment = new FormFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout,fragment).commit();
                    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.i("onActivityResult()",e.toString());
                    mImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }

            }
        }else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    Log.i("onActivityResult()", "end");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // L'endroit où sera enregistrée la photo
        // Remarquez que mFichier est un attribut de ma classe
        mFichier = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpg");
        // On récupère ensuite l'URI associée au fichier
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(mFichier);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Et on déclare qu'on veut que l'image soit enregistrée là où pointe l'URI
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // Enfin, on lance l'intent pour que l'application de photo se lance
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        Fragment fragment = new FormFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout,fragment).commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onFormFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

/**
 *
 * @param uri
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042511/android-camera-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-0-resul

Comment: I watch this question, but it start an activity when I try to display a fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.

---

Option 1.

```
fragmentManager.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

or

```
fragmentManager.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

instead of `fragmentManager.commit();`

---

Option 2.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        //...
        fragmentManager.commitAllowingStateLoss();// or fragmentManager.commit();
        //...
    }, 50);
```