# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: java, android, kotlin

getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null, with Camera Intent in Kotlin, but in JAVA this code is working.
I am very confusing why It is happening.

after Capture Image I am getting this error and crashng app.

```
try {
                        val imageFile = createImageFile()
                        val callCameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                        if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                            val authorities = packageName + ".provider"
                            val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, imageFile)
                            callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
                            startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
                        }
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not create file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }



 fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName: String = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir: File = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if(!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()
        val imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)
        imageFilePath = imageFile.absolutePath
        return imageFile
    }



09-30 13:32:19.145 6918-6918/app.smallbites.com.smallbites E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.smallbites.com.smallbites, PID: 6918
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=null} to activity {app.smallbites.com.smallbites/app.smallbites.com.smallbites.ui.onboarding.AddKidActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
        at app.smallbites.com.smallbites.ui.onboarding.AddKidActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:37)
```

Comment: Somewhere object is `null`, debug your code.

Comment: Post the error log please.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: please check I have updated the question.

Comment: I dont know why people made this question as invalid even this question in not duplicate, because this code is working with JAVA but not in Kotlin, I don't know why people doing like this.

Comment: How have you declared `AddKidActivity.onActivityResult()`?

Comment: yes it is declare onActivityResult()

Comment: Declared, but how? Post the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your data you wanna transmit to. You put **Null** object when it should be **NonNull**

Check the next things:

1. Permission for camera
2. Permission for storage (read/write)
3. Check the place where do you want to store your file, usually, people are fighting with issues internal/external storage.

Also, please, check if your question exists. I guess I found a similar problem.

[android camera : Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042511/android-camera-failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-0-resul)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but same code is working for JAVA but not for Kotlin, and all permissions are granted, camera, write external storage.