# Getting path of captured image in Android using camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have been trying to get path of captured image in order to delete image. Found many answers on StackOverflow but none of them are working for me. I got the following answer:

```java
private String getLastImagePath() {
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor imageCursor = POS.this.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
            null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor
        // .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        return fullPath;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

This code works in Samsung tab but doesn't work in Lenovo tab and i-ball tab.
So, can anyone help me find another solution to do the same? 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

This is my onActivityResult:

```java
if (requestCode == CmsInter.CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    //Bitmap photo = null;
    //photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    String txt = "";
    if (im != null) {
        String result = "";
        //im.setImageBitmap(photo);
        im.setTag("2");
        int index = im.getId();
        String path = getLastImagePath();
        try {
            bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 512, 400, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] bytData = baos.toByteArray();
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result = Base64.encode(bytData);
            bytData = null;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ooM) {
            System.out.println("OutOfMemory Exception----->" + ooM);
            bitmap1.recycle();
            bitmap.recycle();
        } finally {
            bitmap1.recycle();
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432979/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try like this

Pass Camera Intent like below

```java
    Intent intent = new Intent(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CAMERA_IMAGE);
```

And after capturing image Write an `OnActivityResult`, as exhibited by the following code copied from the Stack Overflow answer [Get file path of image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-file-path-of-image-on-android/15432979#15432979) —

> ````java
>     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
>         if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>             Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
>             imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
>             knop.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
>     
>     
>             // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
>             Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
>     
>             // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
>             File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
>     
>             System.out.println(mImageCaptureUri);
>         }  
>     }
>     
>     public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
>         ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
>         String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage,
> "Title", null);
>         return Uri.parse(path);
>     }
>     
>     public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
>         String path = "";
>         if (getContentResolver() != null) {
>             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
>             if (cursor != null) {
>                 cursor.moveToFirst();
>                 int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
>                 path = cursor.getString(idx);
>                 cursor.close();
>             }
>         }
>         return path;
>     } ```
> ````

And check log.

**Edit:**

Lots of people are asking how to not get a thumbnail. You need to add this code instead for the `getImageUri` method:

```
    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        Bitmap OutImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, 1000, 1000,true);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), OutImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

The other method Compresses the file. You can adjust the size by changing the number `1000,1000`

Comment: I don't have any cameraActivity class

Comment: android camera intent is like   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: Check my updated answer,you don't need to write that class name @Shubham

Comment: what about CameraActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, CmsInter.CAMERA_REQUEST);      I'm getting ActivityNotFoundException.

Comment: what does "mImageCaptureUri" stands for??

Comment: Error:(81, 27) error: cannot find symbol method getImageUri(Context,Bitmap)

Comment: (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data") gives me temp file therefore path is also of temp Image. How can I get orignal file?

Comment: the above code make thumbnail image.how can i get full size image from above code?

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "data", null); this line gives me null

Comment: is it a thumbnail or full size image from above code?

Comment: the above code make thumbnail image @ArthurZhixinLiu

Comment: did any one got any fix for this thumbnail image?

Comment: Hi, For me path getting null can anybody help here me

Comment: in getImageUri, I get empty path

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE glad to help :)

Comment: I seen lot of device specific problems coming in android Gallery and Camera image picker now a days. The best is to implement any third party good library . https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker i am using this and working great across device. It also work for android 10

Answer (score 16):

There is a solution to create file (on external cache dir or anywhere else) and put this file's uri as output extra to camera intent - this will define path where taken picture will be stored.

Here is an example:

```
File file;
Uri fileUri;
final int RC_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    private void takePhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), 
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, RC_TAKE_PHOTO);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                //do whatever you need with taken photo using file or fileUri

            }
        }
    }
```

Then if you don't need the file anymore, you can delete it using `file.delete();`

By the way, files from cache dir will be removed when user clears app's cache from apps settings.

Answer (score 5):

Try this method to get path of `original` image captured by camera.

```
public String getOriginalImagePath() {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToLast();

        return cursor.getString(column_index_data);
    }
```

This method will return path of the last image captured by camera. So this path would be of **original** image not of **thumbnail** bitmap.

Comment: what if there is no external storage

Comment: I do get very bad quality using this

Answer (score 5):

Here I updated the sample code in Kotlin. Please note on Nougat and above version `Uri.fromFile(file)` is not working and it crashes the app for that need to implement FileProvider which is safest way to send files from intent. For implementing this refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751453/2599596) or this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b)

```
private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        val isDeviceSupportCamera: Boolean = this.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)
        if (isDeviceSupportCamera) {
            val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                file = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/attachments")!!.path,
                        System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")
//            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
                fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", file!!)
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                }
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.camera_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             if(requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                realPath = file?.path
                 //do what ever you want to do
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to Google Documentation: 
[Camera - Photo Basics](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection,
                    null, null, null);
            int column_index_data = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            image_path = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("path of image from CAMERA......******************.........",
                    image_path + "");
```

for capturing image:

```
    String fileName = "temp.jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    values.clear();
```

Comment: from where do i get the mCapturedImageURI ?

Comment: i tried it but then i'm getting  null pointer on below line        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");