# Android get image path after intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

I made an app. It has 2 options for uploading photo:

1) by taking a photo using camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

2) by picking from gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

My problem is getting file path after these intents in `onActivityResult`.
Is there any methods to get those paths for `new File(path)` , that also takes care of sdk level changes? For example till KitKat is 1 type of file system , after KitKat is other type.

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent

Comment: Just a few moments i will try it

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin for first case (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) works well, but for picking from gallery gives crash  on all test cases

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is getting file path after these intents in onActivityResult.

There will be no file path for the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` approach, because you did not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. If you do provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then you already know what the file path is.

There is no file path for `ACTION_PICK`, insofar as there is no requirement that what the user picks be in a file that you have access to. For example, it could be an image on removable storage. Use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to get the content represented by the `Uri` that you are given.

Comment: onActivityResult returns me the Uri of the file i have chosen from Gallery, sorry if i have explained bad above, but i was meaning to get the correct file path based on that Uri

Comment: @test: Again, there is no way to get a file path that you can necessarily access. Use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to get the content represented by the `Uri` that you are given. "onActivityResult returns me the Uri of the file i have chosen from Gallery" -- only if you consider the `ACTION_PICK` scenario to be "chosen from Gallery". `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a `Uri`, and most camera apps will not return a `Uri` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If you can able to get path from camera then for `Intent.ACTION_PICK` you can directly get uri of image using `data.getData()` and then you can get file path using this method(as suggested in the link provided by Gennadii Saprykin

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
cursor.moveToFirst();
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
return cursor.getString(idx); }
```