# How to call camera image instead drawable

Tags: java, android, flood-fill

How can I call the camera image instead of drawable image?

```
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
selected_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Visit for full example - [link](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)

Comment: how do i get the photopath of the captured image from another activity?

Comment: Here is a sample code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent)

Comment: still dont work. i just want my camera image (uri) pass to another activity to bitmap

Comment: What kind of error you are getting.

Are getting any security error?