# How to share and save the ImageView from First Activity to Third Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

Activity 1:I have an imageview in which the images taken from camera and gallery are set and it works fine. In this Activity there is a right click button which will redirect you to second activity.

Activity 2: In this Activity I have four options

1. Save
2. Share
3. Share Via Instagram
4. Share Via Facebook

Activity 3: From the above four options the third activity works accordingly.
Now I don't know how to pass the image taken in first activity to the third activity.

My Effort: In first Activity image taken from camera:

```
 Intent i=new Intent(Camera.this,SaveVia.class);
 i.putExtra("image", thumbnail );
 startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity SaveVia:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(SaveVia.this, Save.class);
Bitmap receiptimage = (Bitmap)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("image")
startActivity(intent2);
```

In third Activity called Save:

```
Bitmap receiptimage = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("imagepass");
       // receipt.setImageBitmap(receiptimage);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        receiptimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
        File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhotoAR/");
        storagePath.mkdirs();

        File destination = new File(storagePath, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            Toast.makeText(Save.this,"No Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Save.this,"Error Arrived",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Save.this,"Error Arrived again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: try to Use Interface...

Comment: Please look at this. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles). It's a duplicate of your question. Also, as in the linked question it isn't a good idea to actually pass images using parcelable. You would be better of passing a path of the image to your second and third activities and then pull up the image using the path.This would be a much simpler approach. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you pass images (bitmaps) between android activities using bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using File I/O to save the bitmap to disk.  Put the path of the file into your intent bundle using putExtra and recreate the bitmap in your other screens.  Putting large bitmaps into a bundle with an intent can cause TransactionTooLarge exceptions.

Take a look at [Getting path of captured image in android using camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent)

Answer (score 2):

@AND 
You don't need to pass bitmap as Parcelable from one activity.Pass file path in intent from one activity to another.

When you capture image get path in **onActivityresult** and save that path.
And redirect that two second activity.And from that path show your bitmap.Just **Share Uri from path** in share on facebook and Instagram.