# How to get the path or uri of the original Image captured by the camera.

Tags: android, image, android-camera, filepath

How to get the path or uri of the original Image captured by the camera.
when i use the following code it returns me the thumbnail image of the orginal image as its mentioned in google docs. 
I want the path or uri of the orginal image.

I have used the following code but it returns a thumbnail.

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), imageBitmap);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            Intent intent = new Intent(IdentifyActivity.this, detailedActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PATH", finalFile.getPath());
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent

Comment: pass path/uri with camera open intent, camera app will store image on that path

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni I have already tried this method you said. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349762/5097842, it gives an error

Comment: see `MediaStore#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` javadocs

Comment: Have you checked if there is an original image? Many camera apps will not produce an image file if used like you do. You better had started your post with showing the used intent.

Comment: YES there is original image in the gallery @greenapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the `Intent` that you used. I am assuming that it is `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

> How to get the path or uri of the original Image captured by the camera

You don't, unless you supply the `Uri` to use via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

> when i use the following code it returns me the thumbnail image

If you do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is supposed to give you a thumbnail.

> I have already tried this method you said... it gives an error

Then perhaps you should ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide the code that you used and explain in detail what the problem was. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates the use of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

> there is original image in the gallery

There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across ~10,000 device models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed camera apps. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of additional camera apps that the user can install from the Play Store and elsewhere. **Your request could be handled by any of them**, so do not assume that the behavior of one camera app is the same as the behavior for all of them.

There is no requirement for a camera app to write a full-size image to disk when a third-party app makes an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request for a thumbnail. In fact, I would consider it to be a bug if they *do* write out a full size image in that scenario.