# can't be intent to onActivityresult

Tags: java, android

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1337;
private void showCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("category", "camera");
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

I used this code to pick an image from the camera. and this is my activity result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST ) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        filePath = data.getData();
            Log.i("hello", "REQUEST cALL");
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("hello", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

the camera is fine. and I can capture it

but why `imageview` cant pick the photos from camera?

but if I am picking from storage the `imageview` can change the image. 
can you see the false code?

Comment: Did you geve permission to the android app to access the storage??

Comment: [Android’s New Image Capture from a Camera using File Provider](https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954)

Comment: write data? . oke iam try it

Comment: You need to give permission to access storage external and internal also for api > 23 you will need check permission using ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Comment: About file path you could use data.getData().getPath() or ExternalStorageUtil.getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use image file path you have to do like below

**1) Write a method to create an image file**

```
String currentPhotoPath;
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
    storageDir      /* directory */
);

 // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
  currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
  return image;
}
```

**2) Call camera intent**

```
private void showCamera() {
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File

    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                              "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                              photoFile);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
  }
}
```

**3)** Now, you need to configure the FileProvider. In your app's manifest, add a provider to your application:

```
<application>
 ...
 <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
 </provider>
 ...
</application>
```

**4) create a resourse file `res/xml/file_paths.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path name="my_images" 
   path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**Note:** Make sure that you replace `com.example.package.name` with the actual package name of your app.

**5) Obtain the imageFilePath**

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {   
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), currentPhotoPath);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
      // or you can use Glide to show image
      Glide.with(this).load(currentPhotoPath).into(imageView);
  }
```

Hope it works as you expect. for details you can see google [Official documents](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)!

Answer (score 0):

```
data.getData();
```

This one doesnt give you a `filepath` of the captured image

You can follow this one

[Getting path of captured image in Android using camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

       //get the URI of the bitmap from camera result
        Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);


       // convert the URI to its real file path.
        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);

}
```

**This method gets the URI of the bitmap that you can use to convert it to a file path**

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

**this method converst a URI to a file path**

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String path = "";
    if (getContentResolver() != null) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: but the condition to pick image from storage. i can set image view..whats wrong?

Comment: @WildanRomiza edited my answer. data.getData() doesnt give raw bitmap too. sry

Comment: i cant understand . the code in your shared link. give me a simple way? any way

Comment: @WildanRomiza its simple way. camera result wont give you the file path direcly. instead you need to convert the bitmap into file path. which needs some process like getting the URI of the bitmap first, and then translating the URI into the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it will help you.

```
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {   
        Bitmap bitmap= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  
  }
```

Comment: the OP wants to do it from file