# Finding path from Uri android

Tags: android, path, uri

I am developing an android mobile application in which i am trying to upload the picture on server from android app. The .php files are working fine but the java code is not working and showing  error that path is null. I have tried the several types of code but not working at all. Please help.
Thank you
Here is the code.

```
package com.example.pt_connect.attachmentuploadingandgetting;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaring views
    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editText;

    //Image request code
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    //storage permission code
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

    //Bitmap to get image from gallery
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //Uri to store the image uri
    private Uri filePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Requesting storage permission
        requestStoragePermission();

        //Initializing views
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        //Setting clicklistener
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    /*
    * This is the method responsible for image upload
    * We need the full image path and the name for the image in this method
    * */
    **public void uploadMultipart() {
        //getting name for the image
        String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        //getting the actual path of the image
         String path = getPath(MainActivity.this,filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
        } catch (Exception exc) {
           Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }**


    //method to show file chooser
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    //handling the image chooser activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }


    //method to get the file path from uri
    public String getPath(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }


    //Requesting permission
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }


    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadMultipart();
        }Error 
    }


}
```

Comment: check this answer [Siddharth Lele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432979/6401241)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the file path like below

```
String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
         String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
```

on the onActivityResult. I made change to your code. Check below

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();
            filePath = data.getData().getPath();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

I think it will work. If not comment here, we will go for another method