# Getting an images' Uri when a user uploads it from Gallery WITHOUT saving a duplicate

Tags: java, android, android-image

I want to allow users to upload images into my app from their gallery and then I will save their uri in my DB to keep track of upload. Right now I'm getting the Uri from uploaded images as referenced in this SO Answer:

[Get file path of image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432592/get-file-path-of-image-on-android)

The issue with this answer is it requires the image to be saved a second time.

`String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context, img, "title, null);`

I don't want to create duplicate images in a users gallery but I need to get the Uri from the image they upload.  Any suggestions?

Code I'm using now to get the image Uri:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "Imediate Uri: " + selectedImage);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap);

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: The question that you linked to is for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, which is not "from their gallery". What is your code that you are using to get an image?

Comment: @CommonsWare Updated my question with my exact code.

Comment: `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();` -- is this from `onActivityResult()`? If so, what is your `Intent` action? And, since `selectedImage` is a `Uri`, why can you not use that `Uri`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest posting the image to a storage bucket, like Amazon S3, Firebase Storage / Google Cloud Storage. This'll generate a URI / URL, and you could post that URI to your database.

I'm not sure if this entirely answers your question but I hope I might have pointed you somewhere in a good direction.

P.S.: Most of those storage solutions also have built-in APIs so you wouldn't be obligated to post the URI to the databse.